# I killed Patches. What are the consequences?

Tags: elden-ring

I accidentally killed patches. I get a little button mashy sometimes, and, well, as Elden Ring bosses go? He’s just so squishy.

I’ve turned in his bell bearing at round table hold, so I have Margit’s Shackle anyway.

What are the other long term consequences of my action? What else have I missed out on?

Comment: Would you mind some spoiler?

Comment: @Skye-AT That's what the spoiler tags are for :)

Comment: I assume you're talking about killing him at the first encounter?

Comment: @pboss3010 yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not be able to acquire two gestures:

> **Extreme Repentance** is the first one and requires you to win the first Patches fight, initiate another and then surrender. **Patches' Crouch** is the second one and it's only available when you complete his entire quest line.

You would not be able to complete one of the quests in

> Volcano Manor,

which awards you with a weapon and an armor set (which is somewhat interesting option for heavy load / high poise builds) :

> [Magma Whip Candlestick](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Magma+Whip+Candlestick) and [Bull Goat Set](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Bull-Goat+Set)

That one Patches quest is an optional part of the larger quest line, you still will be able to complete it and get the final reward.

Of cause you will also miss multiple conversations/interactions with Patches, like his typical

> "push you down to some hole" thing in Mount Gelmir

and another NPC interaction:

> dialogue with [Tanith](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Tanith)  after giving her [Dancer's Catanetes](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Dancer%27s+Castanets)

Comment: You also won't be able to do something as part of a NPC quest, but apparently that quest has been dummied out anyways (the item Patches gives you is just ignored by the NPC)

Comment: @pboss3010 I hope this quest gets some update for that item to actually work somehow. For now it's just couple of missed conversations. Let me include that in my answer though