# Is there any good reason not to just murder all of the merchants for my own convenience?

Tags: elden-ring

There are a few dozen merchants scattered around the world of Elden Ring. Some of them are happily sitting right next to a convenient site of grace, but others like to hang out in weird caves or cliff faces in the middle of nowhere, and which are a right pain in the rear to get to.

The thing is, some of these merchants sell essential adventuring supplies like Ballista Bolts that are hard to acquire elsewhere.

Now, when you kill a merchant in Elden Ring, they will drop a [Bell Bearing](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Bell+Bearings), which can be turned in to the Twin Maiden Husks at Roundtable Hold, at which point the merchants inventory, becomes part of the Husks inventory. This is extremely convenient! If I murder every merchant, I can simply turn in all of their bell bearings, and now I have One Stop Shopping at Roundtable Hold! I no longer need to bounce all over the world to restock.

Is there any good reason not to do this? Will my actions have unforeseen consequences?

Comment: “You should not kill the Merchants because that is a bad thing to do and you will feel bad”, is, IMO, not a good answer. I have already [murdered Patches in cold blood.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397743/i-killed-patches-what-are-the-consequences) I am beyond remorse. I will not feel bad. Just FYI.

Comment: AFAIK there's no reason other than "you'll feel bad". Every single one of them except the man that stays at first church (I forgot his name, but the one guy that tells you where the Blaidd is located) doesn't have any questline, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

There is no good reason not to do this.

You can kill all merchants to have all their stuff at the Twin Maidens.

I do it in all my playthrough and I always was able to finish the game. And like that no forth and back to those merchants in the map. All at the same location.

**You can still sell your stuff to the Blacksmith in the Round Table Hold**

Answer (score -1):

## You can't sell stuff to the Twin Maiden Husks.

All of the merchants of the Grand Caravan have the option to sell items to them in exchange for runes. The Twin Maisen Husks, who accept their Bell Bearings, do not.

Whether or not you'd want to sell items to them is up to you, but it's arguably more efficient than throwing your fourth duplicate set of Haligtree Gauntlets or whatever into your item box and forgetting about them.

Comment: You can sell to the Blacksmith, so just a short walk from the twin maidens